# Extract rar file through Junrar and then delete the archive

Tags: java, file, archive, delete-file, rar

I'm using [junrar](https://github.com/junrar/junrar) but I have a problem to delete the archive after extraction.
This is the code:

```
ExtractArchive extractArchive = new ExtractArchive();  
extractArchive.extractArchive(new File(archiveFilePath), new File(destDirectory));
```

after this code I can't delete file associated to archiveFilePath. 
I tried both `new File(archiveFilePath).delete();`  and `apache commons io`

```
FileDeleteStrategy.FORCE.delete(new File(archiveFilePath));
```

but I receive false or one exception because file is used from another process.
Someone has had the same problem with this library? Can I remove the file in other ways? Thanks

Here there is a confirm of the issue:
https://github.com/edmund-wagner/junrar/issues/28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in `ExtractArchive.extractArchive(...)` is defect as it creates internally an `Archive` instance but it never calls `close()` to free up it's resources and file handles.

On Windows this results in a locked file that can not be deleted unless the JVM ends or the garbage collector has collected all object instances of that Archive and therefore has freed the file handles.

On Windows there is no other way to delete the file!

Comment: As I thought, to fix it I have overridden the extractArchive method including new Archive object into try() brackets